# What causes my raspberrypi.local connection to fail after my PC is suspended?

Tags: window, mdns

After suspend my pc, raspberrypi.local stop working but I can continue to work with IP. If I shutdown or restart windows everything turn to work properly.

I used another pc to connect (and work normally) after encounter the problem to make sure that is not raspberry. I've also tried to pause the firewall and it's not the source of the problem. I think the problem come from something that is modified before or immediately after suspension or hibernation, can be?